# How can I make my question "Why do these communicators from Star Trek differ?" clearer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked why there are differences between the models of communicators shown here: [Why do these communicators from Star Trek differ?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196324/why-do-these-communicators-from-star-trek-differ)

How can I be more clear?

Comment: The question has been reopened now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's too much unclear about the question. The first paragraph, which is essentially the entirety of your question, looks fine to me. That said it might be better to show where the different communicators come from, or at least where some of them come from to explain the differences easier.

Your gif and the RIP comment with the image also seem highly irrelevant to your question so it would be best, in my opinion, if you edited them out all together.

Beyond that there really doesn't seem like much to do, seems pretty clear. However, note I am not a Star Trek fan so there might be something to do with tying it to Star Trek that could be unclear but if so I don't know what.